# Cassandra Hector Client: Is a RangeSlicesQuery on Composite Row Keys possible when using Random Partitioning?

Tags: cassandra, range, composite, hector, composite-primary-key

Is there any way to range query rows with a composite row key when using random partitioning?

Im workling with column families created via CQL v3 like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products ( rowkey CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type,UTF8Type,UTF8Type) 
PRIMARY KEY, prod_id varchar, class_id varchar, date varchar);
```

The data in the table looks like this:

```
RowKey: 6:3:2:19
=> (column=class_id, value=254, timestamp=1346800102625002)
=> (column=date, value=2034, timestamp=1346800102625000)
=> (column=prod_id, value=1922, timestamp=1346800102625001)
-------------------
RowKey: 0:14:1:16
=> (column=class_id, value=144, timestamp=1346797896819002)
=> (column=date, value=234, timestamp=1346797896819000)
=> (column=prod_id, value=4322, timestamp=1346797896819001)
-------------------
```

I’m trying to find a way to range query over these composite row keys analog to how we slice query over composite columns. Following approach sometimes actually succeeds in returning something useful depending on the start and stop key I choose.

```
Composite startKey = new Composite();
startKey.addComponent(0, "3", Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
startKey.addComponent(1, "3", Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
startKey.addComponent(2, "3", Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
startKey.addComponent(3, "3", Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
Composite stopKey = new Composite();
stopKey.addComponent(0, "6", Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
stopKey.addComponent(1, "6", Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
stopKey.addComponent(2, "6", Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
stopKey.addComponent(3, "6" , Composite.ComponentEquality.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);

RangeSlicesQuery<Composite, String, String> rangeSlicesQuery = 
HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, CompositeSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());
rangeSlicesQuery.setColumnFamily(columnFamilyName);
rangeSlicesQuery.setKeys(startKey,stopKey);
rangeSlicesQuery.setRange("", "", false, 3);
```

Most of the time the database returns this:

```
InvalidRequestException(why:start key's md5 sorts after end key's md5.
this is not allowed; you probably should not specify end key at all,
under RandomPartitioner)
```

Does somebody have an idea if something like this can be achieved WITHOUT using the order preserving partitioner? Do I have to build a custom row key index for this use case?

Thanks a lot!

---

**Additional information:**

What I’m trying to do is storing sales transaction data in a table which uses both composite row keys to encode date/time/place and composite columns to store information about the sold items:

The set of items per transaction varies in size and includes information about size, color and quantity of every item:

```
{ ... items :
[ { item_id : 43523 , size : 050 , color : 123 , qty : 1 } ,
  { item_id : 64233 , size : 048 , color : 834 , qty : 1 } ,
  { item_id : 23984 , size : 000 , color : 341 , qty : 3 } ,
… ] }
```

There’s also information about where and when the transaction happened including a unique transaction id:

```
{ trx_id : 23324827346, store_id : 8934 , date : 20110303 , time : 0947 , …
```

My initial approach was putting every item in a separate row and let the application group items back together by transaction id. That’s working fine. But now I’m trying to leverage the structuring capabilities of composite columns to persist the nested item data within a representation (per item) like this:

```
item_id:’size’ = <value> ; item_id:’color’ = <value> ; item_id:’qty’ = <value> ; …
43523:size = 050 ; 43523:color = 123 ; 43523:qty = 1 ; …
```

The rest of the data would be encoded in a composite row key like this:

```
date : time : store_id : trx_id
20110303 : 0947 : 001 : 23324827346
```

I need to be able to run queries like: All items which were sold between the dates 20110301 and 20110310 between times 1200 and 1400 in stores 25 - 50. What I achieved so far with composite columns was using one wide row per store and putting all the rest of the data into 3 different composite columns per item:

```
date:time:<type>:prod_id:transaction_id = <value> ; …
20110303:0947:size:43523:23324827346 = 050 ;
20110303:0947:color:43523:23324827346 = 123 ;
20110303:0947:qty:43523:23324827346 = 1 ;
```

It’s working, but it doesn’t really look highly efficient.
Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating one row per partition, so it should be clear that RandomPartitioner will not give you ordered range queries.

You can do ordered ranges *within* a partition, which is very common, e.g. http://rubyscale.com/blog/2011/03/06/basic-time-series-with-cassandra/ and http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra

Comment: Thanks for the links! That’s what I tried so far. Please have a look at the additions I made to my initial question.

The ordering of the results isn’t the problem, it’s more about the InvalidRequestException…

I have to admit I’m really no expert in hash functions. So I just have to accept that the hashed value of a composite row key [‘3:3:3:3’] is bigger than [‘6:6:6:6’]?

Than I guess my plan has no future...